# Image src binding with KnockoutJs initiates two requests

Tags: knockout.js

Given a binding like this

```
<img data-bind="attr: { src: (adv.packageImagesVm.imageUrlBase() + $data) }" alt="product image" />
```

The images DO get correctly displayed
but I can see in the network requests that **two** requests are fired:

1: `myAccount.blob.core.windows.net/public/myImage.png` (ok)

and (inexplicably)

2.`http://localhost/public/myImage.png`

Does anyone know why the second request happens?

edit: a bit more of the code:

```
<ul class="thumbnails" data-bind="foreach: packageImagesCollectionDto().PackageVoucherImageUrls">
    <li class="span2" data-bind="if: $data, visible: $data">           
        <img data-bind="attr: { src: (adv.packageImagesVm.imageUrlBase() + $data) }" alt="product image" />                        
    </li>
</ul>
```

edit: here's the result of `<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data)"></div>`

```
{
    "packageImagesCollectionDto": {
        "PackageId": 2,
        "PackageImageUrls": [
            "/public/product/55/AAID220.jpg",                
            "/public/product/80/retreat.jpg"
        ],
        "PackageVoucherImageUrls": [
            "/public/product/55/voucher/AAFL2xx.jpg",                
            "/public/product/80/voucher/ddVoucher.jpg"
        ]
    },
    "imageUrlBase": "http://xyz.blob.core.windows.net"
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for your view model? Mainly `PackageVoucherImageUrls` and `imageUrlBase()`

Comment: Could you add a span to see the url ?
 <span data-bind="text : (adv.packageImagesVm.imageUrlBase() + $data) " />

Comment: @Damien - the span shows the combined elements eg: xyz.blob.core.windows.net/public/product/80/voucher/ddVoucher.jpg

Comment: I can't see any errors, may be you could create a fiddle.

Comment: @Damien I'll learn how to do fiddles as you rightly suggest (I always have problems simulating the ajax/json calls, but I'll persist). Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like adv.packageImagesVm.imageUrlBase() is updated after packageImagesCollectionDto() so knockout will be doing the foreach as soon as the collection is updated and then as soon as the imageUrlBase updates it'll then update the src binding to the correct value based on both of the observables.  If that's the case, you would see the localhost as the first request.

How is the view model populated?

Are you able to move "imageUrlBase" to the top of the object?  It isn't neat but it should force knockout to update/create that observable first and as nothing is bound to it yet it won't fire anything unnecessarily and then when the dtos are bound you'll already have the value of imageUrlBase so it won't make the localhost request.

I hope that all makes sense! :-)

Comment: That's it! Setting imageUrlBase before the other observables fixed the problem. Well Worked Out Doctor (I'll do a fiddle next time as @Damien suggested). Thanks all